# Change CSS style for price (tag)

Tags: magento2, price, css, frontend

does anyone know how can I change the style for the price in product listings (not on product details page) on front-end? I would like to make the price bigger and change its color. I tried but I simply cannot locate the CSS (LESS) file that controls the style of the price tag.

Please see the image

[image]

Comment: do you have some custom theme and css file or trying with LESS ?

Comment: yes, i am using custom theme that extends Luma theme

Answer (score 1):

To change price or CSS / Less for catalog page copy _module.less file and paste it in your theme directory here you will be able to make any change you want :

copy :

> /theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less

And Paste it in :

> /Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less

Then you can make any change you want :

NOTE : after making changes delete pub/static/frontend and var/view_processed folder and deploy static content again.

Answer (score 0):

```
.product-item .price-box .price {
    ...
}
```

You can debug the less & css files, more informations in : [How CSS and LESS files are preprocessed and how to debug them](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html)